# django login test with selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium

In my application I have a login page. I am currently using `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.model`.

This is my test with `Selenium`, based on `PhantomJS` (because I am in a container):

```
class TestLogin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='this_is_a_test', password="dockercompose")


    def test_good_login(self):
        expected_url = "http://localhost:8080"
        self.driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys("this_is_a_test")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_password').send_keys("dockercompose")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_form').submit()
        print(self.driver.page_source)
        assert self.driver.current_url == expected_url
```

My test failed, and this is the `print(self.driver.page_source)` :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form method="post" id="login_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
                   value="zRNkCIYxymsGLFKcZlpLTjbfBcvZxAVFTrAQyvy2wTyiKeISZCRIkraVV7OfS6DG">
            <ul class="errorlist nonfield">
                <li>Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.</li>
            </ul>
            <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" value="this_is_a_test" autofocus=""
                                                                 maxlength="254" required="" id="id_username"></p>
            <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" required="" id="id_password">
            </p>
            <button name="submit_button" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did a `User.objects.all()` into the test and user `this_is_a_test` has been created.

If you can help, it could be nice :) Thanks!

### Requirements:

Django==1.11
selenium==3.4.0

### Update

I have created a `User` with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, my `User` is always `(username="this_is_a_test", password="dockercompose"`. Then my test has succeeded.
So it seems that `User` created with `django.contrib.auth.model` is not stored into my test database.

This in my settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'database_container',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'TEST': {
            'USER': 'django',
            'PASSWORD': 'django',
            'NAME': 'my_db_test'
        }
        } 
}
```

Comment: <li>Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.</li> Probably your username/password entered are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to replace

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_form').submit()
```

with

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('submit_button').click()
```

and try, also wait until the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I have solved my problem.

Using LiveServerTestCase was a solution to my issue.:)